# Jquery slider hide prev and next when first or last

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I want to hide the Prev and next button, on this code.
I guess I can toggle the buttons based on offset value? How?

And the Last page keeps scrolling, they should stop when the images ends.
http://jsfiddle.net/2tUZ4/1/

```
function slide(container) {
    var $container = $(container);

    var resizeFn = function () {
        var small = $(window).width() < 800;
        $container.toggleClass('four', small).toggleClass('six', !small);
    }

    var toggleButtons = function () {        
    }

    var nextPane = function (e) {
        e && e.preventDefault();
        var $container = $(this).closest('.grid-container');
        var $items = $('.items', $container);
        var offset = $items.css('marginLeft').replace('px', '');
        var width = $container.width() + parseInt($('.item', $container).css('marginRight').replace('px', ''));
        $items.css('marginLeft', offset - width);
    }

    var prevPane = function (e) {
        e && e.preventDefault();
        var $container = $(this).closest('.grid-container');
        var $items = $('.items', $container);
        var offset = $items.css('marginLeft').replace('px', '');
        var width = $container.width() + parseInt($('.item', $container).css('marginRight').replace('px', '')); 
        $items.css('marginLeft', offset + width);
    }

    resizeFn();
    $(window).resize(resizeFn);

    $('.next', $container).click(nextPane);
    $('.prev', $container).click(prevPane);

}


slide('.grid-container.one');
slide('.grid-container.two');
slide('.grid-container.three');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compare the width, like this - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2tUZ4/3/)

```
var nextPane = function (e) {
        e && e.preventDefault();
        var $container = $(this).closest('.grid-container');
        var $items = $('.items', $container);
        var offset = $items.css('marginLeft').replace('px', '');
        var width = $container.width() + parseInt($('.item', $container).css('marginRight').replace('px', ''));
        $items.css('marginLeft', offset - width);

        if( $(this).parent().find('.items').width() + (offset - width) < width){
        $(this).hide();
        }
    }
```

Comment: could you please have a look at it? prev button is not hiding.

Comment: Oh, I thought that you need to hide the next button only. When do you want the prev button to hide??

Comment: hide prev and next when first or last, also when is last, its scrolling back to the first slide. could u double check please?

Comment: you there? could u help?

Comment: is not right mate! the prev button still showing and if u click it keeps scrolling left. also the next one, keeps scrolling right